# TapGestureRecogniser doesn't work at all in the newly created UIViewController but works in all the old UIViewControllers made before

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[Proof that gesture is being added but not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6DDx.png)

```
import UIKit

class PlaybackSpeedController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func tapDetected(_ tap : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

This hello never gets triggered. what am I missing? Funny how I used to play with gestures but don't understand why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `UIViewController`'s `view.backgroundColor` property to be some colour instead of default one solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I add a transparent view that has the same frame as the superview.

```
let transparentView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
transparentView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

And just adding the gesture recognizer on that view

Comment: I have tried this, but no luck.. moreover I made a whole UI in the previous controller full of pan, pinch, scale gestures.. all of them work very well. but in the new controller files I am making, this is the case.. I am not sure why in the world this happens lol

Comment: Chances are that you didn't connect this specific view controller in your storyboard. Make sure to set it to the PlaybackSpeedController

Comment: I am using entirely programatic UI, like I ditched the storyboard from `info.plist` and I am using window to make them visible. in the debug view hierarchy, the view has the gesture recogniser attached to it as well but the gesture isn't being detected, which is driving me crazy.

Comment: Any chance your project is on GitHub? Strange problem for sure

Comment: omg, I just added colour to background and it worked, but is this some kinda bug?

Comment: Definetely a bug, color should not change that. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure view is having userInteraction enabled & is tappable directly on screen, for that make sure your new view controller frame is correct.

Comment: It's the viewController main view so I guess there's no need to set frame of it. There's no possibility to use auto layout on the main view itself I guess. however looks like the issue is with colour of main view should not be clear may be. not sure about the exact bug, but setting view colour solved this. that was the only thing different from my previous files and I just tried it, hilariously it works.